# How do I get the position of a txtfield inside a popoverview with respect to ipad screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITextfield in a tableview in a view controller, and I am displaying this view  in a UIPopOverView. I  wanted to know how can I get to know the position of the textfield with respect to IPAD screen...so that i can move my tableview upwards on Textfield editingDidBegan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the convertPoint:toView: or convertRect:toView: methods of UIView.

So for example, to get the textField's bounds relative to the window, say

```
CGRect *bounds = [textField convertRect:textField.bounds toView:window];
```